# Little assistance needed regarding linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

Actually this script is well know, [DDos Deflate](http://deflate.medialayer.com/) .

But after using, i notice im getting some emails without ip like

```
Banned the following ip addresses on Thu Mar 21 21:19:01 CET 2013

138 with 138 connections
```

From [source](http://codepad.org/YUziwU8O#line-1), and from "netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr" command, i notice maybe we need to avoid first line , because looks like first line is just number of total open connections.

[image: command]

Can someone who know this scripting language, check if i`m right and fix it? Maybe some additional basic check like if ip == number of connections , break?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to do what you ask :

```
netstat -ntu |
    awk 'NR>1{sub(/:.*/, "", $5); print $5}' |
    sort |
    uniq -c |
    sort -nr
```

Comment: Have you tested the second snippet ?

Comment: yes, there is still one with no blank 2nd parameter. I think i need one more conditional on script source

Comment: Can you copy/paste `netstat -ntu` output on a pastebin ? Substitute your own ip with anything  if you want. (if IP is public)

Comment: It's much better if you give response to my question when you post something to get help